# How do I remove the surrounding quotes/code block formatting in my regex?

Tags: regex, quotation-marks

I have this regex to match words, code blocks, and things surrounded by quotes. The problem is that this regex includes the code block formatting and quotation marks.

```` /(```[^```]*```)|("[^"]*")|[^" \n]+/g ````

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. What language are you using? Would you please offer some examples of what you're trying to match?

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to use a non-capturing group, i.e. (?:...)

Comment: This: `[^```]*` is the same as having a character-class with only one backtick `[^']*` (had to use plain quote in this second example) … it does _**not**_ mean 3 backticks in a row. In addition to non-capturing groups as Oliver mentions, you probably want negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

So, I spent a few hours learning regex and I created some regex code that does exactly what I need:

`` /(?:(?<=`{3})[a-z]*\n[\s\S]*?\n(?=`{3}))|(?:(?<=")[^"]*(?="))|[^" \n(`{3})]+/g ``

This matches code blocks excluding markdown, strings within quotation marks excluding the quotes, and individual words.